# Beautifulsoup data scraping collect number from website

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I would like to use beautifulsoup to extract number.
My code is as follows:

```
future=data3.find_all('span',class_='instrument-price_last__KQzyA')
    
print(future)
```

It will return:

```
span class="instrument-price_last__KQzyA" data-test="instrument-price-last">23,989.5</span
```

How can I extract the 23989.5 out of this information?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `text` attribute:

```
future = float(data3.find_all('span',class_='instrument-price_last__KQzyA').text.replace(',', ''))
```

And:

```
print(future)
```

Would give:

```
23989.5
```